Is it possible to align the complex phases of a diagonal matrix while preserving the given decomposition?
If $U$ is unitary, $A$ is complex symmetric, $t$ is the transpose, and $U_1^t A U_1$ yields a diagonal matrix $D_c$ with singular values of A with some complex phase, is there a way to make $U_2^t A U_2$ such that it equals that diagonal matrix but with phases aligned (real matrix) $D_r$? I read a suggestion of multiplying $U_1$ on the right by a "suitable" diagonal unitary matrix (and I am not sure if the suggestion really meant $U_1$ or $D_c$), but I was not able to see how such matrix exists neither how it would preserve the stated decomposition.

If $D_c$ is a diagonal matrix with entries along the diagonal of phases $\theta_n$, then $P^tD_cP$ with $P$ being the diagonal matrix with entries $\exp(-i\theta_n/2)$ is a diagonal matrix consisting of real (in fact, nonnegative) entries. Now just take $U_2 = U_1P$. (This is assuming you actually meant transpose by $^t$, instead of conjugate transpose.)
